# Magento2 Adding product attribute option via API

Tags: magento2, api

I am adding new colors to the colors attribute via API. This works fine, but I want to send all my options in 1 request. Now I have to do multiple POST request to **rest/V1/products/attributes/color/options**

This is my code

```
protected $resourcePath = 'rest/V1/products/attributes';

foreach($options as $option) {
$optionData = [];

$optionData = [
    AttributeOptionInterface::LABEL => $option,
    AttributeOptionInterface::SORT_ORDER => 100,
    AttributeOptionInterface::IS_DEFAULT => false,
    AttributeOptionInterface::STORE_LABELS => [
        [
            AttributeOptionLabelInterface::LABEL => $option,
            AttributeOptionLabelInterface::STORE_ID => 1,
        ],
    ],
];

    $this->addColorAttribute($optionData);
}

public function addColorAttribute($optionData)
{
    $attributeCode = 'color';

    $serviceInfo = [
        'rest' => [
            'resourcePath' => $this->resourcePath . '/' . $attributeCode .'/options',
            'httpMethod' => Request::HTTP_METHOD_POST,
        ]
    ];

    return $this->client->request($serviceInfo,
        [
            'attributeCode' => $attributeCode,
            'option' => $optionData,
        ]
    );
}
```

How could I send all my `$optionData` to the API in 1 request so all the options are addded to the product attribute **color** ?

Comment: I may be overlooking it, but from what I can tell there is no support for bulk processing in the Magento2 API.

Answer (score 1):

Send them all into either
put or Post at /V1/products/attributes/{attributeCode}

and it will create them,

FYI im having problems updating the labels later, which looks like its not possible via the API right now

Answer (score 1):

You can directly create attribute with all attribute options by send the below  json to this endpoint `"POST /V1/products/attributes"`

```
{
  "attribute": {
    "is_wysiwyg_enabled": false,
    "is_html_allowed_on_front": false,
    "used_for_sort_by": false,
    "is_filterable": true,
    "is_filterable_in_search": true,
    "is_used_in_grid": true,
    "is_visible_in_grid": false,
    "is_filterable_in_grid": true,
    "position": 0,
    "apply_to": [],
    "is_searchable": "1",
    "is_visible_in_advanced_search": "1",
    "is_comparable": "1",
    "is_used_for_promo_rules": "0",
    "is_visible_on_front": "0",
    "used_in_product_listing": "1",
    "is_visible": true,
    "scope": "global",
    "attribute_code": "att_with_options",
    "frontend_input": "select",
    "entity_type_id": "4",
    "is_required": false,
    "options": [
      {
        "label": "Option1"
      },
      {
        "label": "Option2"
      },
      {
        "label": "Option3"
      }
    ],
    "is_user_defined": true,
    "default_frontend_label": "Att Label",
    "frontend_labels": null,
    "backend_type": "int",
    "source_model": "Magento%5C%5CEav%5C%5CModel%5C%5CEntity%5C%5CAttribute%5C%5CSource%5C%5CTable",
    "default_value": "",
    "is_unique": "0"
  }
}
```

this code should work for you